# Joy sometimes changes linux controller mapping

Tags: ros, microcontroller, ros-kinetic, joy, teleoperation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

When launching joy I occasionally experience a case where I have a wired xbox360 controller plugged to the machine and joy instead uses wireless mapping? This is obviously an issue for when I am operating my robot as the left trigger for wired mapping is Left/Right Axis stick right for wireless mapping. Can anyone point me to if there is an option to force joy to use a wired mapping or perhaps if it is xboxdrv that is presenting the issue?

Thanks in advance for all help.

EDIT in response to gvdhoorns comment:
The [Joy package](http://wiki.ros.org/joy) maps the arrays of axes and buttons differently depending on whether the controller is [wired](http://wiki.ros.org/joy#Microsoft_Xbox_360_Wired_Controller_for_Linux) or [wireless](http://wiki.ros.org/joy#Microsoft_Xbox_360_Wireless_Controller_for_Linux). My problem is that the controller is always wired but occasionally will map to wireless.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311031/joy-sometimes-changes-linux-controller-mapping/) by [PG_GrantDare](https://answers.ros.org/users/38516/pg_grantdare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2018-12-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-19**:
At least for me personally it would help if you could clarify what a "wireless mapping" and a "wired mapping" are.

**Comment by [PG_GrantDare](https://answers.ros.org/users/38516/pg_grantdare/) on 2018-12-19**:
@gvdhoorn edit added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This problem was solved. It appears that on an older computer (not my own) xboxdrv and xpad were fighting for the controller. Based on who got it first was the mapping. I uninstalled xboxdrv and kept xpad and solved this.

---

Originally posted by [PG_GrantDare](https://answers.ros.org/users/38516/pg_grantdare/) with karma: 52 on 2019-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0